# Type argument required for a class while extending in kotlin

Tags: android, generics, kotlin

So my problem is simple,
In java if i have a base class like this:

BaseViewModel.Java

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel<N> extends ViewModel {
```

I can extend this class to other classes without defining the generic argument N, like this:

```
public class BaseFragment<V extends BaseViewModel> { //this is fine
```

but kotlin throws an error with this approach asking for the generic definition.

```
class BaseFragment<V: BaseViewModel>: Fragment() {// one type argument expected
```

how to avoid this?

Comment: It's fine just because Java tolerates raw types.

Comment: `//this is fine` actually not really

Comment: That is not fine, it should be `BaseFragment<N, V extends BaseViewModel<N>>`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it (since others don't explain why this is wrong).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kotlin doesn't allow to use raw types as Java does. Thus, you have to specify some type for your `V : BaseViewModel`:

```
class BaseFragment<V: BaseViewModel<Any>>: Fragment() {
```

It is equivalent for your Java code cause `V extends BaseViewModel` basically means `V extends BaseViewModel<Object>`

Comment: That last depends on how you mean "basically". There are important differences.

Comment: I don't know what author is trying to achieve since we have only class signatures. And I've posted answer only from perspective of that signatures. To see full picture and give more detailed answer we need more code samples which describes how `BaseViewModel` can be used. Anyway you've already posted nice link which explains such differences.

Comment: Maybe it makes sense to go with `V: BaseViewModel<*>` but again, I don't know whole picture.